# Hamiltonian in Majorana basis

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, majorana-fermions

I read (for example here: [cond-mat/0010440](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440)) very often that if we transform the Hamiltonian from a fermionic basis to the basis of Majorana operators by expanding the fermionic operators in real and imaginary part $c = a + ib$ with $a^{\dagger} = a$ and $b^{\dagger} = b$, then the corresponding Hamiltonian can be written as

$$
H = \frac{i}{4}\sum_{lm}A_{lm}a_{l}b_{m}\text{.}
$$

Now the matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric ($A^{T} = -A$). My question is now, is there a general reason why $A$ is skew-symmetric?

Comment: Have you tried to actually expand out the Hamiltonian and see if it works out?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on some examples and it works everytime! My question is, is there fundamental reason why this is so?

Comment: It's just because $H$ is Hermitian in the first place !

Comment: It is because Majorana operators anti commute.

Comment: Are you sure you want one $a_l$ and one $b_m$ in your formula, and not all possible combinations of all Majorana modes?